# Deleted Ubuntu Partition, now stuck

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I am a new Linux user. I started a few weeks ago with Ubuntu and have been teaching myself.

I have Windows 10 and then dual booted Ubuntu. I wanted to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition so booted from a USB and used gparted. I couldn't seem to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition so thought I would just delete it and reinstall it, starting again and giving it more space.

So after deleting the Ubuntu partition in gparted I restarted the PC, with the USB drive in to reinstall ubuntu from scratch. But the menu never appeared and instead it's gone straight to grub rescue>.

After using the ls command it displays (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

I just want to get Ubuntu up and running again. Any help would be most appreciated. As I say I am very new to Linux, I just passed the LPI Essentials exam and wanted to experiment so am seeing this all as a learning curve.

Thanks very much for your time,
Ed

Comment: Looks like you booted straight into GRUB, I'd suggest trying to boot from your USB again, and make sure you hit the appropriate key to enter the Boot Menu to boot from your USB.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for replying. I can confirm that the bios is set to boot off the usb, however it still went straight to the grub rescue prompt. It says error no partition, entering rescue mode then grub rescue prompt.

Comment: That's weird I just restarted again and now it's booted from the usb, it didn't do that before. Presumably more I can install Ubuntu again.